# Disable Checkbox without greying

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

In wpf forms, i have a checkbox which needs to be disabled without being greyed out.

x.xaml

```
<CheckBox Content="check" Name="AP" DockPanel.Dock="Top"
          IsChecked="{Binding Path=check}"    
          Margin="0,0,6,8" />
```

i tried  which is not working

Comment: i tried with <Style.Triggers> which is not working

Comment: WPF and Windows Forms are two completely different frameworks. I suggest removing any mention of "Windows Forms" from your question, because it seems to be related only to WPF.

Comment: i should have written wpf forms...wrongly entered it

Answer (score 10):

`<CheckBox IsHitTestVisible="False" Focusable="False" />`

Answer (score 0):

The code you have on display will not change the appearance of the button.

You have a number of choices. Two are:

- Create a `<Button>` instead of a `<CheckBox>`, but set its `<Button.Style>` to appear to be just the empty square. Then use an `ICommand` in your viewmodel and bind it to the `Command` property of the button.
- Re-skin using the `<CheckBox.Style>` to describe a different appearance for the `<CheckBox>`. This is more than using triggers, it involves some 200-level knowledge of how to style a control.

Comment: I'll add code if you like; I need to sleep for a few hours first.